# Why equatable enums with associated values don't get == defined automatically

Tags: swift

I see in enums with associated values all over the place.
Say something like:

```
enum Foo {
    case bar(param0: Bar)
    case baz(param0: Baz)
    case foo
}
```

typically has:

```
extension Foo: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
        "\(lhs)" == "\(rhs)"
    }
}
```

Why is something like that not generated out of the box and has to be written explicitly?
As I said that pattern is all over the place resulting in quite a bit of boilerplate.

Comment: It’s quite common that the associated values are of different types and there is no requirement that they conform to Equatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Bar` and `Baz` both conform to Equatable the compiler can synthesise the Equatable conformance to enum `Foo`:

```
struct Bar: Equatable {}
struct Baz: Equatable {}

enum Foo {
    case bar(param0: Bar)
    case baz(param0: Baz)
}
```

The following declaration compiles:

```
extension Foo: Equatable {}
```

The relevant compiler feature is defined in [SE 0185](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md):

**Conditions where synthesis is allowed**

For brevity, let P represent either the protocol Equatable or Hashable in the descriptions below.

Synthesized requirements for enums

For an enum, synthesis of P's requirements is based on the conformances of its cases' associated values. Computed properties are not considered.

The following rules determine whether P's requirements can be synthesized for an enum:

The compiler does not synthesize P's requirements for an enum with no cases because it is not possible to create instances of such types.

The compiler synthesizes P's requirements for an enum with one or more cases if and only if all of the associated values of all of its cases conform to P.

Comment: @AntonTropashko It doesn't matter if there are cases without associated data. If you were to compare two different cases, i.e. a `.foo` with a `.bar(param0: someBar)` the result is always `false`. Only if you want to compare to enum values with the same case, for example `.bar(param0: otherBar)` with `.bar(param0: someBar)`, then the compiler inserts `return someBar == otherBar`.

Comment: @AntonTropashko Added the relevant Swift Evolution Proposal where this feature is defined.